# Axios is undefined in React, error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I have installed the axios package with: `npm i axios`.
I import it in my redux action and Im trying to `axios.post()`, but the axios object is undefined.
It posts successfully with `.fetch()`
I'm using "axios": "^0.19.2" & "react": "^16.13.0".

```js
import { axios } from "axios";

// Login User
export const login = () => dispatch => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email: "jan@gmail.com", password: "password" })
    };
    axios.post("https://freunder.uber.space/login", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.json())
  };
```

[Browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d5LD.png)

Comment: Axios uses a default export, not a named export. Change it to `import  axios from "axios"`;

Comment: Change `import { axios } from "axios";` to: `import axios from "axios";`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Import axios as a default instead of a named export like so:

```
// This
import axios from 'axios';

// Instead of this
import { axios } from "axios";
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, I made the same mistake in the import statement.

Answer (score 0):

I tried you code, its returning 401 error and i am not facing the error you posted . You can see the response as well

[image]

The response :

[image]